# jQuery's contents() methods in pure JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, pure-js

So I've been trying to do the following bit of code without importing the jQuery library:

```
$(".parent-class").contents().find(".child-class").css("color", "red");
```

I know that [.contents()](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) ***gets the children of each element in the set of matched elements including text and comment nodes***, from the jQuery docs, but I don't think I understand what that description means. I've tried getting the children of `.parent-class` with:

```
let theChildren = document.querySelector('.parent-class').children;
```

but this doesn't do the same thing as `.contents().find(".child-class")` does.

**EDIT**: As requested in the comments I've made a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61099280/equivalent-of-jquerys-contents-find-chained-methods-in-pure-js) as this one seems to not be specific enough.

Comment: `contents()` is primarily used in jQuery when you need to select text nodes. In the first code sample you have it's not needed at all, as you use `find()` to select elements with a class.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I've tried omitting the content() method in my original code but that breaks the functionality. I'm trying to edit the styles of an embedded Twitter feed and I could only do that by getting the module's child nodes using the following snippet `$(".twitter-timeline").find(".timeline-Tweet-text").css("margin-bottom", "-10px");`

Comment: In that case you would be better served by asking a new question about the specific problem instead of a general question about the purpose of `contents()`

Comment: I will edit the question then to better suit the specific problem.

Comment: You should start a new question, as you now have answers to this one

Comment: I've posted the new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61099280/equivalent-of-jquerys-contents-find-chained-methods-in-pure-js

Answer (score 1):

`contents()` is primarily used in jQuery when you need to select text nodes. In the first code sample you have it's not needed at all, as you use `find()` to select elements with a class. These lines of jQuery would serve the same purpose:

```
$(".parent-class").find(".child-class").css("color", "red");
$(".parent-class .child-class").css("color", "red");
```

In plain JS this would be:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.parent-class .child-class').forEach(el => el.style.color = 'red');
```

Note `querySelectorAll()` there. This will return a nodeList which you need to iterate through to update the style in the same way the jQuery code does.

There is no explicit JS equivalent of `contents()` because you traverse manually to find the nodes you want to target, or use `querySelector()`, `getElementByX()` etc to target the elements.